# Selenium Webdriver: Compare Driver and Browser Versions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

so I am working on a Java automation project with Selenium Webdriver, but I've run into problems keeping the drivers up to date with the browsers I am using. I have used the Capabilities class to get either the driver or browser version (I don't know which), and I need to know how to get the other so I can compare the two for automatic updates. Here is my basic structure:

```
 `Capabilities cap1,cap2;
 cap1 = ((RemoteWebDriver) test).getCapabilities();
 cap2 =//function to access browser information;
 if(cap1.getCapability("chromeDriverVersion")!=/* cap2 function to get browser version*/){
updateDriver();
}
else{
proceed();
}`
```

What I'm looking for is that cap2 method. What would you suggest?